# How to implement interface in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to implement interface in javascript

if yes do you have any example ?

Answer (score 19):

First of all, there is not built in support for traditional abstraction in JavaScript. At least, there are not any types like interfaces and abstract classes. However, interface can be implemented using Object.create method and prototypes. For more information, visit [here](http://www.yusufaytas.com/achieving-abstraction-in-javascript/).

Comment: Using Object.create and prototypes actually simulates inheritance and not interfaces.

Answer (score 11):

Quoting from an article written by Mark McDonnell:

> In JavaScript there are no true "classic" Object-Oriented features,
>   but through clever usage of the language you can emulate an Interface
>   for use with a JavaScript API.

See the following for the complete article:

http://www.javascriptbank.com/how-implement-interfaces-in-javascript.html

Comment: The link seems to be broken